# iOS 12 Shortcuts with WhatsApp

Tags: siri, whatsapp.app, ios, shortcuts-app

With the new **Shortcuts** app introduced in iOS 12, you can create a Shortcut that sends a message to a specific WhatsApp contact.

When you choose that option, the Shortcut will open the WhatsApp Application and your text will be put into the input field.

**What I want:** I want that the WhatsApp application **stays** closed. And I don't get any feedback. It should just send a specific message to a recipient.

**Workaround**: If you use Siri to send a **specific** message to **one** recipient over and over again, this specific action will show up as a **suggestion** in the Apple Shortcut app. When you use that as an action, the Message will be sent, **without** any feedback. That's exactly what I want, the only catch is that I have to **train** Siri to actually suggest the things I want to send and **additionally** I can't send Emojis that way.

**Q:** Is there a better way to send WhatsApp messages with the iOS Shortcuts app, **without** ever having to open the WhatsApp app and/or pressing a button?